# Inserting a function into main part

Tags: c++, function

I'm a beginner and I have a little problem about calling a function into the main part of the program.

```
#include <iostream>

#include<cmath>
int getAbsProd(int a, int b)
{
cout<<"Insert integer: "<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout<<"Insert another integer: "<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"The absolute value of the multiplication is: "<<abs(a*b)<<endl;
return abs(a*b);

}


int main()
{

cout<<getAbsProd();
return 0;
}
```

I'm using codeblocks, couldn't call math.h, somewhere it was suggested to call cmath.

Comment: Change `cout<<getAbsProd()` to `cout<<getAbsProd(1,2)` or something similar...

Comment: Move the declaration of `a` and `b` inside function. Like `int getAbsProd() { int a, b; ... }`.

Comment: noob001, if my answer worked please accept the answer so this question will be closed

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Now that I'm reading over your code, it seems like you don't need to set parameters in your method `getAbsProd`. Remove the `int a` and `b` so it looks like this:

```
int getAbsProd()
```

Then you should be good to go!

**Explanation:**

Parameters are something you need to have in your methods if you are going to call it from `main` or another method, and you need to supply it input from `main`. In your case, you're not giving it any input yourself from your code, but rather calling in `cin`. So you don't need to have `(int a, int b)` in the parameter, but rather create it as local variable in the method itself.

```
int getAbsProd()
{
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
cout<<"Insert integer: "<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout<<"Insert another integer: "<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"The absolute value of the multiplication is: "<<abs(a*b)<<endl;
return abs(a*b);

}
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

<s>You need to supply the methods with the parameters it needs in order to calculate the value. For example, your `main` method should be similar to:</s>

```
int main()
{

cout<<getAbsProd(1, 2); //you need to have an int a, and an int b
return 0;
}
```

Now, your function should calculate the absolute value of 1 (remember, this is the `int a` that you're giving to your function), multiplied by 2 (second parameter that you're supplying the function with, i.e. `int b`).

Your output should be `2` in this case.

For more information, check out this tutorial about functions in C++:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Hope this helps. If there is any additional things, feel free to comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getAbsProd` expects 2 parameters: `int a` and `int b`. You're calling it without any parameters. For example, to pass 5 for both `a` and `b` call it like this :

```
int main()
{
  cout << getAbsProd(5, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and found the error.

There are two possible solutions to make your code work.

**Solution 1: Declare getAbsProd() without any parameters**

and declare integers a and b within the function

like,

```
int getAbsProd() {
int a,b;
cout<<"enter value of a";
cin>>a
.
.
return 0;
}
```

**Solution 2: If you want to declare function to accept parameters, then ask for numbers in main from user and then call the function with 'a' and 'b' as parameters**

```
int main () {
int a,b;
cout<<"enter value of a";
cin>>a;
cout<<"enter value of b";
cin>>b;
cout<<getAbsProd(a,b);
return 0;
}
```

make any of the two changes and your code should work.

Hope that helps,
Rakesh Narang